# Javascript/jQuery Is it possible to break out of a function through another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, fade, breakout

I'm doing a script that rotates li's in a given ul. I'd like to know whether it is possible to break a recursion I have when one of the li's is hovered. Ideally I'd create a boolean whether the recursion should continue or not, as I'd like to have this to break when I have a video embed in it in the future. I've just started it so this is basically what I've got.

HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ulRotator").rotate();
 });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <ul id="ulRotator" style="width:500px; height:500px;">
     <li style="background-color:red;"></li>
        <li style="background-color:blue;"></li>
        <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
        <li style="background-color:green;"></li>
        <li style="background-color:grey;"></li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

Javascript:

```
    (function( $ ){

 var rotator;
 var rotatorLi;

 $.fn.rotate = function() {
  rotator = this;
  rotatorLi = rotator.children('li');

  rotatorLi.css('width',rotator.css('width')).css('height',rotator.css('height'));
  rotator.addClass('rotator');
  $(rotatorLi[0]).addClass('current');

  moveSlides('right');
 };


 moveSlides = function(direction){
  var current = $(rotator).find('li.current');  
  var currentPosition = $(rotatorLi).index(current);
  var slideCount = $(rotatorLi).length - 1;

  var next;
  if (direction == 'right'){
   if(currentPosition == slideCount){
    next = rotatorLi[0];
   }else{    
    next = rotatorLi[currentPosition+1];
   }
  }
  else if (direction == 'left'){
   if(currentPosition == 0){
    next = rotatorLi[slideCount];
   }else{    
    next = rotatorLi[currentPosition-1];
   } 
  }

  $(current).delay(6000).fadeOut(500,function(){
   $(current).removeClass('current');
   $(next).addClass('current');
   $(next).css('display','block');
   moveSlides(direction);
  });
 };
    })( jQuery );
```

CSS

```
    .rotator li
    {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:0;
 display::block !important;
 list-style-type:none;
    }
    li.current
    { 
 z-index:1 !important;
    }
```

Also note that I consider myself a huge newbie when it comes to Javascript, I might be going around this in a very idiotic way without me knowing it, any pointers would be appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woul set a variable like `abort` to true using a public function in the mouseover and check it in the first line of `moveSlides`. If it's set to true simply `return` out of the function.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, so if a function is called while the recurring function is running, it does not have to wait?

I'm assuming that when the function that stops the other one can also start it again when it's finished? Let's say using hover?

Comment: It does not have to wait no. Yes you can start it again using a function.

Comment: @Matthew - In this case the recursive call to `moveSlides()` is the very last thing done (tail recursion) so in any case there's nothing pending to do when the inner call returns.

Comment: @Stephen, I'm not sure I understood that.

Comment: @Matthew This SO [What is tail recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33923/17300) question may help explain it.

Comment: @Stephen, I'm sorry about that, I understand what tail recursion is, I didn't understand what you're trying to point out in the comment.